# Embedded OrientDB distributed mode - failed to create database

Tags: distributed, embedded-database, orientdb

I have setup OrientDB (orientdb-community-1.7-20140428.151223-168-distribution) in embedded distributed mode. I am able to start embedded orientDB in 2 separate JVMs and verified both servers are part of the cluster.

```
Members [2] {
    Member [localhost]:2434 this
    Member [localhost]:2435
}
```

Then I logged into console and created a database called Tinker. In console it says the database was created successfully but I cannot connect to the same database from 2nd node.

```
orientdb> create database remote:localhost:2425/Tinker admin admin memory

Creating database [remote:localhost:2425/Tinker] using the storage type [memory]...
Connecting to database [remote:localhost:2425/Tinker] with user 'admin'...OK
Database created successfully.

Current database is: remote:localhost:2425/Tinker
orientdb {Tinker}> connect remote:localhost:2424/Tinker admin admin               

Disconnecting from the database [Tinker]...OK
Connecting to database [remote:localhost:2424/Tinker] with user 'admin'...
Error: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OConfigurationException: Database 'Tinker' is not configured on server
```

I see the below error message on the server log. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

2014-04-28 13:56:13:849 INFO Saving distributed configuration file for database 'Tinker' to: /Users/peddi/Downloads/orientdb-community-1.7-SNAPSHOT/databases/Tinker/distributed-config.json [OHazelcastPlugin]
2014-04-28 13:56:13:856 INFO [node1398358958901] found no previous messages in queue orientdb.node.node1398358958901.Tinker.request [OHazelcastDistributedMessageService][node1398358958901]<-[node1398358958902] error on installing database Tinker in /Users/peddi/Downloads/orientdb-community-1.7-SNAPSHOT/databases/Tinker
**com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.memory.OStorageMemory cannot be cast to com.orientechnologies.orient.server.distributed.ODistributedStorage**
-> com.orientechnologies.orient.server.hazelcast.OHazelcastPlugin.executeOnLocalNode(OHazelcastPlugin.java:643)
-> com.orientechnologies.orient.server.hazelcast.OHazelcastDistributedDatabase.onMessage(OHazelcastDistributedDatabase.java:454)
-> com.orientechnologies.orient.server.hazelcast.OHazelcastDistributedDatabase$1.run(OHazelcastDistributedDatabase.java:248)
-> java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)Exception in thread "hz._hzInstance_1_orientdb.cached.thread-4" com.orientechnologies.orient.server.distributed.ODistributedException: **No response received from remote nodes for auto-deploy of database**
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.hazelcast.OHazelcastPlugin.installNewDatabases(OHazelcastPlugin.java:844)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.hazelcast.OHazelcastPlugin.entryAdded(OHazelcastPlugin.java:528)
    at com.hazelcast.map.MapService.dispatchEvent(MapService.java:684)
    at com.hazelcast.map.MapService.dispatchEvent(MapService.java:65)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.EventServiceImpl$LocalEventDispatcher.run(EventServiceImpl.java:529)
    at com.hazelcast.util.executor.StripedExecutor$Worker.run(StripedExecutor.java:142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
    at com.hazelcast.util.executor.PoolExecutorThreadFactory$ManagedThread.run(PoolExecutorThreadFactory.java:59)

Comment: What's your distributed cfg.json? Can you report also the JSON in the output after the node joined?

Comment: Below is config from log:2014-04-29 12:53:37:184 INFO updated distributed configuration for database: Tinker:
----------
{
  "version":1,
  "replication":true,
  "autoDeploy":true,
  "hotAlignment":false,
  "offlineMsgQueueSize":0,"clusters":{
    "internal":{
  "replication":false
},
    "index":{
  "replication":false
},
    "*":{
  "replication":true,
  "readQuorum":1,
  "writeQuorum":2,
  "failureAvailableNodesLessQuorum":false,
  "readYourWrites":true,"partitioning":{
    "strategy":"round-robin",
    "default":0,
    "partitions":[["<NEW_NODE>","node1398358958901"]]
    }
}
    }
}

Comment: default-distributed-db-config.json is the one that came with installation. I don't think I modifed in that file.

Comment: Hi Luca,
Could you please at the above configuration and let me know if there is anything wrong with the config. We want to use OrientDB as embedded distributed server and since I can't get past the first issue of creating database, I am completely blocked by this issue. I really need to prove OrientDB is going to work for us in embedded and distributed mode.

Thanks

Comment: You've only one node online. Look at partitions. Maybe you've copied the cfg of the first server where the id is "node1398358958901". Remove or change the id in server2/config/orientdb-dserver-config.xml

Answer (score 0):

You've only one node online. Look at partitions. Maybe you've copied the cfg of the first server where the id is "node1398358958901".

Remove or change the id in server2/config/orientdb-dserver-config.xml